# How to handle XML string %Like% search in C#

Tags: c#, xml, search

As I know I can search DB with Sql syntax `%like%`.

Now I am working with XML, how can I handle the same search condition for XML file in C#?

I want to search the string and find it with part of the Keyword. Not the full text of keyword.

```
   <bookstore>
     <book genre="autobiography">
       <title>The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin</title>
       <author>
         <first-name>Benjamin</first-name>
         <last-name>Franklin</last-name>
       </author>
       <price>8.99</price>
     </book>
     <book genre="philosophy">
       <title>The Gorgias</title>
       <author>
         <name>Plato</name>
       </author>
       <price>9.99</price>
     </book>
   </bookstore>
```

Assume I am working with the sample XML above. How can I code in C# to search "**%jami%**", then return "**Benjamin**". Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traverse the XML file and do a [String.Contains(...).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx)

Comment: Thank you . I found a sample code about String.Containers(). It works quite well as I need.

Comment: That'll work, but Garett's suggestion of XPath or Linq To XML is the more elegant approach.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways this can be done, depending on the version of .NET you are working with. You can use [XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.aspx), or my preference [Linq To XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

Here are a few useful links:

- [XPath Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx)
- [XPath String Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256180%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) - Look at the contains function
- [Example Linq TO XML Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943906.aspx)